# Looping between matched strings(consider one dataset) then the control should move to the next dataset

Tags: shell

My input data is below :

```
2019-08-27 06:24:31.055  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : Message From WEAREORANGE
2019-08-27 06:24:32.559  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : EMAIL =  12816
2019-08-27 06:24:32.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : carrier name is..WEAREORANGE will be processed
2019-08-27 06:24:32.574  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Preparing Carrier Body----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.574  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Body Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.574  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Preparing Carrier Sub----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.574  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Subject Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.576  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier ID Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.576  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Start Date Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.576  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier End Date Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.576  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Impact Duration Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.576  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Status Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.577  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Outage Reason Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.577  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Ciruits Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:24:32.593  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : Inserted null
2019-08-27 06:24:32.594  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : fetch sesam info for carrier name ..WEAREORANGE
2019-08-27 06:24:32.632  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : No. of Mails : 1
2019-08-27 06:24:32.632  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Count of Refrence in  one Mail 1
2019-08-27 06:24:32.633  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Start Date  2019-08-29 17:00:00
2019-08-27 06:24:32.633  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : End Date  2019-08-30 00:00:00
2019-08-27 06:24:32.633  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Differene 25200000
2019-08-27 06:24:32.635  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Impact Duration  7.0
2019-08-27 06:24:32.635  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.SendMail                         : :::::::SEND MAIL HTML FUNCTION:::::::::
2019-08-27 06:24:32.813  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.SendMail                         : :::::::SEND MAIL HTML FUNCTION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY:::::::::
2019-08-27 06:24:32.813  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : :::::::Body Sent:::::::::::::::
2019-08-27 06:31:09.027  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : Message From TEAM
2019-08-27 06:31:09.537  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : EMAIL =  12817
2019-08-27 06:31:09.537  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : carrier name is..TEAM will be processed
2019-08-27 06:31:09.555  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Preparing Carrier Body----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.556  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Body Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.556  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Preparing Carrier Sub----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.556  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Subject Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.557  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier ID Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Start Date Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier End Date Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Impact Duration Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.u.CommonUtil                       : mKindWork value: Due to planned transmission work the services listed may experience a break to service during the change window.
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Status Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Outage Reason Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.560  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : ---Carrier Ciruits Prepared----
2019-08-27 06:31:09.575  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.c.i.BaseCarrierProcessing          : Inserted N9367007L
2019-08-27 06:31:09.575  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : fetch sesam info for carrier name ..TEAM
2019-08-27 06:31:09.606  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : No. of Mails : 1
2019-08-27 06:31:09.606  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Count of Refrence in  one Mail 1
2019-08-27 06:31:09.608  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Start Date  2019-09-04 07:00:00
2019-08-27 06:31:09.608  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : End Date  2019-09-04 19:00:00
2019-08-27 06:31:09.608  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Differene 43200000
2019-08-27 06:31:09.608  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Impact Duration  12.0
2019-08-27 06:31:09.614  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : Circuit values N9367007L
2019-08-27 06:31:09.688  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : RECORD FOUND IN SESAM
2019-08-27 06:31:09.688  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : carrier name is.. TELSTRA to be set in cmt request
2019-08-27 06:31:09.690  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : CMT REQUEST IS.... TELSTRA2709896 false
2019-08-27 06:31:09.691  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : CMT Request JSON {"loginUser":"Email.Bot","circuitType":"REF","carrierName":"TELSTRA","noOfCircuits":"1","additionalInfo":"NA","circuitId":"N9367007L","customerCode":"685790","customerCity":"Leinster","customerCountry":"AU","startDate":"2019-09-04 07:00:00","windowDuration":"12.0","maxImpactDuration":"480","reasonForChange":"Due to planned transmission work the services listed may experience a break to service during the change window.","maintenanceChangeType":"PLANNED","otherNotifyReceipents":"","usId":null,"comments":null,"routerName":"SLER010","isValidated":"N","carrierRef":"2709896","circuitStatus":null,"essatAckNumber":null,"cessationDate":null,"customerCountryName":null,"eventType":"LOGGED","isStartDateInUtc":"false"}
2019-08-27 06:31:25.121  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : CMT RESPONSEcom.orange.carrierbot.bean.CmtWebServiceResponse@6ebb2758
2019-08-27 06:31:25.121  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ValidateData                     : MAINTENANCE IS LOGGED SUCCESSFULLY REF/2019.39033
2019-08-27 06:34:31.162  INFO 23839 --- [        Timer-0] c.o.c.s.ReadMail                         : Message From WEAREORANGE
```

My dataset(matching string) will start from  "Message From" and end when another "Message From" is witnessed. I need to find keywords in between, which will not be an issue. My issue is, I don't know how to ask bash to read between datasets (i.e Between "Message From" till "Message From") and then move to the next line where "Message From" appears and read that dataset.

I am new to shell scripting and I am stuck at this point, please help!

Comment: Message From COLT
.fetch sesam info for carrier name ..COLT
No. of Mails : 1
Count of Refrence in  one Mail 1
Successful Response
:::::::SEND MAIL HTML FUNCTION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY:::::::::
Message From WEAREORANGE
carrier name is..WEAREORANGE will be processed
fetch sesam info for carrier name ..WEAREORANGE
No. of Mails : 1
Start Date  2019-08-29 17:00:00
End Date  2019-08-30 00:00:00
Impact Duration  7.0
:::::::SEND MAIL HTML FUNCTION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY:::::::::
:::::::Body Sent:::::::::::::::
Message From TEAM

Comment: So everything from the line containing `Message From WEAREORANGE` up to the line with `Message From TEAM` is one dataset? If so `awk` is your friend.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the response.
Yes, Everything from : Message From WEAREORANGE up to the line with Message From TEAM is one dataset. Now, the task is to find keywords between those datasets and move to the next dataset. How to do this please

Comment: Also, the appearance of "Message From" keyword is completely random. It can appear at any line number (eg for my last log, linenum are 1,7,13,25,30,39 so on)

Comment: Well, using `awk` with the *field-separator* of `':'` will allow you to check if the 2nd field begins with `"Message From"` (e.g. `$2 == /^\s*Message From/`) and if so you can output all lines up to the next `"Message From..."` into a new file, say `WEAREORANGE.txt`, and then repeat until your run out of lines. `awk` is the Swiss Army Knife of text processing and well worth taking the time to learn, even if it seems really cryptic at first. (it will be orders of magnitude faster than looping in shell)

Comment: Thanks for the help David, let me try to output each dataset into a new file, apply string checking on that new file and then move to the next dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation that splits the data above (contained in the file `log`) from the line containing `"Message From WEAREORANGE"` up to the line containing `"Message From TEAM"` into separate files `WEAREORANGE` and then outputting lines to the file `TEAM` once the line containing `"Message From TEAM"` is reached.

```
awk -F: -v fname="" '
    $4 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*Message From/ {fname=$4; sub(/^.*From[[:blank:]]*/,"",fname)}   
    fname {print $0 > fname}
' log
```

(**note:** this will also append the last line in your data above that also contains `Message From WEAREORANGE` into the same `WEAREORANGE` file. You can change this behavior by keeping a counter to append to each filename, etc..)

The above `awk` command:

- `-F: -v fname="" '` sets the *field-separator* to `':'` and initializes the variable `fname` empty;
- `$4 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*Message From/` if the 4th field (not 2nd sorry) matches the regular-expression: zero or more whitespace followed by `Message From`, then

  - `fname=$4` set the output filename to the 4th field; and
  - `sub(/^.*From[[:blank:]]*/,"",fname)` remove everything up through `"From"` and any whitespace from `fname`.
- `fname {print $0 > fname}` if `fname` is set, output the line to the file `fname`.
- `' log` read lines from the file `log`.

The command does just that. Running the above in the directory containing `log` (or whatever your filename is) will separate and output records to the files `WEAREORANGE` and `TEAM`.

The [GNU awk Users Guide - 9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) describes the string functions available and provides a reference for `sub`. The rest of the guide is a very good learning tool.

What `awk` does is read each line and then apply each *Rule* you have written. There are 2-rules above:

```
    $4 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*Message From/ {fname=$4; sub(/^.*From[[:blank:]]*/,"",fname)}
```

and

```
    fname {print $0 > fname}
```

So if you follow the logic, the first just matches any time there is a `"Message From XXX"` found as the 4th field (splitting fields on `':'`) and then trims the `"Message From"` part away leaving the name to use as `fname`.

The second rule just redirects the line to the output file `fname` so long as `fname` is set.

**Creating Unique Filenames**

If there are multiple entries of `"Message From WEAREORANGE"`, etc... and you want those as unique filenames, you can do so by keeping a counter indexed by the base part of the filename and appending that to the filename before writing to it. For example you may want filenames like `WEAREORANGE_1.txt` and then `_2.txt`, etc.. You can do that with simple string concatenation, e.g.

```
awk -F: -v fname="" '
    $4 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*Message From/ {
        fname=$4
        sub(/^.*From[[:blank:]]*/,"",fname)
        a[fname]++
        fname=fname"_"a[fname]".txt"
    }   
    fname {print $0 > fname}
' log
```

Where:

- `a[fname]++` the array `a` indexed by the base `fname` after the trim (e.g. `WEAREORANGE`) and it holds the count of the number of times `WEAREORANGE` has been seen,
- `fname=fname"_"a[fname]".txt"` just uses the base `fname` an underscore, the count and then `.txt` at the end to form `WEAREORANGE_1.txt` the first time it is seen and then increments the number sequentially each time a new `"Message From WEAREORANGE"` is encountered.

That is but the tip-of-the-iceberg on what `awk` is capable of. (pay the price -- take the time to learn it)

Comment: Issue : I think your scripts makes datasets where Message From keywords are distinct. What if Keywords are same, how to handle such scenerio ?
# cat carrierBot.log | grep -n "Message From"
1: Message From ORANGE
55:Message From ORANGE
109:Message From ORANGE
163:Message From ORANGE
252:Message From ORANGE
# cat ORANGE | grep -n "Message From"
1: Message From ORANGE
55:Message From ORANGE
109: Message From ORANGE
163: Message From ORANGE
252: Message From ORANGE

Comment: Sure, you can concatenate to the filename like `fname {a[fname]++; print $0 > fname"_"a[fname]".txt"}` ti create files `ORANGE_1.txt`, etc... (where `a[fname]++` just keeps a counter of the number of times `fname` was seen and gives each file a new suffix with `.txt` at the end)

Comment: I am sorry, but am I doing anything wrong here. I tried with concatenate the output file, which works. But the output files getting created are numbered from ORANGE_1.txt till ORANGE_304.txt, where each file is containing a single line from the original log. It is not creating a single file (containing 1 dataset) for all the lines between mentioned keywords. Please suggest what changes can be made to this?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was just shown as an example. the `a[fname]++;` should go in rule-1, e.g. `{fname=$4; sub(/^.*From[[:blank:]]*/,"",fname); a[fname]++; fname=fname"_"a[fname]".txt"}` Now it will only update when you match the row with `"Message From XXXX..."` in it.